# Action Form not work

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<form action="/en2/maps-<?php echo $id; ?>/?=. ($_GET['textSearchTerms']).&=. ($_GET['locationSearchTerms'])."><!--Relative url to the page that your map is on-->

Distination: 
<select name="textSearchTerms" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option value="alfamart">Alfamart</option>
        <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
    </select> 
Location: 
<input type="text" name="locationSearchTerms">

<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

`<form action="/en2/maps-<?php echo $id; ?>` not work...
any idea?

I want this link for my form action:

`http://indonesia.com/en2/maps-alfamart/?textSearchTerms=alfamart&locationSearchTerms=denpasar`

thanks

Comment: Have you checked what the value is displayed in the form by inspect the form?

Comment: I want http://visit2indonesia.com/en2/maps-alfamart/?textSearchTerms=alfamart&locatio‌​nSearchTerms=denpasar, the problem is <form action="/en2/maps-<?php echo $id; ?>.....the cript not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
    <?php
        $id="alfamart";
        $textSearchTerms = isset($_GET['textSearchTerms']) ? $_GET['textSearchTerms'] : "";
        $locationSearchTerms = isset($_GET['locationSearchTerms']) ? $_GET['locationSearchTerms'] : "";
        $url = "/en2/maps-".$id."/?textSearchTerms=".$textSearchTerms."&locationSearchTerms=".$locationSearchTerms;
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="GET">
    Distination:
    <select name="textSearchTerms" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
            <option value="alfamart">Alfamart</option>
            <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
        </select>
    Location:
    <input type="text" name="locationSearchTerms">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

Added form method GET and your php variable in php tag

Comment: good one, but can you please tell him this code works if and only if the file extension is `.php` , because i think the OP is facing that problem. So please add it as a note. Thanks.

Comment: @Abed : If you run your current page with '?textSearchTerms=alfamart&locationSearchTerms=denpasar' you will get the url as you want. Check by inspect element.

Comment: Or are you submitting the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<form action="/en2/maps-<?php echo $id; ?>/?=. ($_GET['textSearchTerms']).&=. ($_GET['locationSearchTerms']).">
```

with

```
<form action="/en2/maps-<?php echo $id; ?>/?textSearchTerms=<?php echo $_GET['textSearchTerms']; ?>&locationSearchTerms=<?php echo $_GET['locationSearchTerms']; ?>">
```

Note:- You missed `textSearchTerms` and `locationSearchTerms` in your form action parameter before `=`.

Comment: not work.......like http://visit2indonesia.com/en2/maps-%3C?textSearchTerms=alfamart&locationSearchTerms=denpasar

Comment: I think string concatenation is wrong for  form action

Comment: not work the problem is <form action="/en2/maps-<?php echo $id; ?> from <selection> <select name="textSearchTerms" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="alfamart">Alfamart</option>
  <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
 </select>

Comment: @AbedPutra Not getting you, and your code is messed so nothing get from that tooo....